# Menu strip is not shown in form designer, even though its code exists

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2012

Last night, I was working on my project in C# by visual studio 2012. Suddenly I encountered a few errors from visual studio and then menu strip went into hiding. Now I haven't menu strip in my form and I lost all it visual option, but I have all it code in my `formdesigner.cs` file. I can't make all option again because it is hard and Time-consuming and I must create a menu strip by new names.and create all sub items by new names.

How I can resume my lost menu strip to form?

This is a part of my designer code:

```
 this.Main = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.userOptionTtm = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.changePasswprdTSM = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.CalenderOption = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.CalenderOption2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.CalenderOption1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.hollydays = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.ExitTsm = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.useroption = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.ReportsTSM = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.loanListTsm = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
 this.FeutureJobsTSM = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
```

and i have properties for all sub items of menu , that i was created (or defined ) previously. for example :

```
//
// Main
//
this.Main.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
this.userOptionTtm,
this.CalenderOption,
this.ExitTsm});
this.Main.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9F);
this.Main.Name = "Main";
this.Main.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(62, 20);
this.Main.Text = "تنظیمات";
//
// userOptionTtm
//
this.userOptionTtm.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
this.changePasswprdTSM});
this.userOptionTtm.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10F);
this.userOptionTtm.Image = global::TimeManagment.Properties.Resources._0079;
this.userOptionTtm.Name = "userOptionTtm";
this.userOptionTtm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(165, 24);
this.userOptionTtm.Text = "تنظیمات کاربر";
this.userOptionTtm.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.chengePasswordTtm_Click_1);
```

and in my form code, I have all code of this menu. for example:

```
private void FeutureJobsTSM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FeutureReportForm.isJobs = true;
    FeutureReportForm fr = new FeutureReportForm();
    fr.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

or

```
private void changePasswprdTSM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chengePasswordForm cpf = new chengePasswordForm();
    cpf.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Does your designer file have a line for `this.Controls.Add(this.Main);`?

Comment: I add this line , but an exception Occurred :    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: So the designer file didn't have it?  Where did you add the line?

Comment: No,Don't have . I add the line inside  InitializeComponent(){ .... } area .

Comment: Well, make sure you add it at the end of that InitializeComponent method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx everybody. I added these lines to Form.Designer.cs file and my problem fixed.

```
this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
this.menuStrip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] 
{ this.Main,this.ReportsTSM });
this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
this.menuStrip1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(589, 24);
this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 10;
this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);     
private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
```